# Shell script comparing dates

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cygwin

I'm working on a shell script that scrapes a date off a webpage and then checks if it is in the last three days of the current date (running it in Cygwin). If the test passes, it simply echoes "PASS", and if it fails, it echoes "FAIL";

However, when I run my script, I get the following:

```
integer expression expected: 1317618000
FAIL
```

Here is the script:

```
updateStr=$(curl "http://www.mywebsite.com" | grep "Last Update")
dateStr=(`echo $updateStr | sed -e 's/.*Last Update: \([^<]*\)<.*/\1/'`)
update=$(date -d "$dateStr" +%s)
epoch=$(date -d "-3 days ago" +%s)
test "$update" -ge "$epoch" && echo "PASS" || echo "FAIL"
```

Any ideas on what the issue is?

**Edit**

Here is the result of running `bash -x` on the script:

```
$ bash -x check_date.sh
++ curl http://www.mywebsite.com
++ grep 'Last Update'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6542  100  6542    0     0    789      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--  1544
+ updateStr='                <span style="float:right">Last Update: 10/3/2011 2:
'8:45 AM</span></p>
++ echo '<span' 'style="float:right">Last' Update: 10/3/2011 2:58:45 'AM</span><
'p>
++ sed -e 's/.*Last Update: \([^<]*\)<.*/\1/'
' dateStr='(10/3/2011 2:58:45 AM)
' +%ste -d '(10/3/2011 2:58:45 AM)
+ update=$'1317618000\r'
++ date -d '-3 days ago' +%s
+ epoch=$'1317938194\r'
+ test $'1317618000\r' -ge $'1317938194\r'
: integer expression expected1317618000
+ echo FAIL
FAIL
```

**Update**

I tried removing the carriage returns that appear in the date outputs, but it's still not working. Here is the updated script:

```
updateStr=$(curl "http://mywebsite.com" | grep "Last Update")
dateStr=$(echo $updateStr | sed -e 's/.*Last Update: \([^<]*\)<.*/\1/')
update=$(date -d "$dateStr" +%s | tr -d '\r')
epoch=$(date -d "3 days ago" +%s | tr -d '\r')
echo "Last Update: $update"
echo "Epoch Date:  $epoch"
test "$update" -ge "$epoch" && echo "PASS" || echo "FAIL"
```

And here is the result:

```
$ bash -x ./check_date.sh
++ curl http://mywebsite.com
++ grep 'Last Update'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6542  100  6542    0     0  17398      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 19704
+ updateStr='                <span style="float:right">Last Update: 10/6/2011 2:
'0:02 AM</span></p>
++ echo '<span' 'style="float:right">Last' Update: 10/6/2011 2:40:02 'AM</span><
'p>
++ sed -e 's/.*Last Update: \([^<]*\)<.*/\1/'
' dateStr='10/6/2011 2:40:02 AM
' +%ste -d '10/6/2011 2:40:02 AM
++ tr -d '\r'
+ update=$'1317886802\r'
++ date -d '-3 days ago' +%s
++ tr -d '\r'
+ epoch=$'1318184767\r'
' echo 'Last Update: 1317886802
Last Update: 1317886802
' echo 'Epoch Date:  1318184767
Epoch Date:  1318184767
+ test $'1317886802\r' -ge $'1318184767\r'
: integer expression expected: 1317886802
+ echo FAIL
FAIL
```

Comment: Can you show what is in `echo $dateStr`

Comment: can  you add -x to your #!/bin/bash so that it prints out when each command is run?

Comment: I am going to guess, without trying myself, that test does not like those carriage returns. Otherwise I don't see why it would fail.

Comment: @frankc: Yeah, that's probably it. I'm surprised I didn't notice them before.

Comment: `-3 days ago` is 3 days in the future - is that really what you're trying to compare to?

Comment: Please don't use `command && echo Pass || echo Fail` !
Check and run `echo a && touch /x || echo b`! I know that `echo` will not return not null but if you want change `echo Pass` to "complex" program (e.g. create a file, show a dialog, etc.), you will surprise :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The carriage returns might be in your script itself. Try running `dos2unix` on your script.

Comment: How can i run dos2unix in my script ? I'm using this script http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/ and getting this error.

Comment: I run the command on cygwin terminal dos2unix filename , but still its showing integer expression expected message

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
update=$(date -d "$dateStr" +%s | tr -d '\r')
epoch=$(date -d "-3 days ago" +%s | tr -d '\r')
```

That will get rid of the carriage returns at the end of each number, which might help.

Comment: Hmm...for some reason that doesn't seem to be stripping the carriage returns off the numbers, so I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Is it Gnu `tr`? That seems to work on my system. Check your manpage, I guess. You could also try typing C-v C-m to put an actual carriage return character in your command line, but that would be iffy inside a script.

Comment: I'm guessing it's related to using Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

bash is determining from context (the presence of '\r' in this case) that these are strings and not integers.  The '-ge' binary operator expects integer arguments and so it's throwing an error.  Tom Zych's suggestion will work, as well as using string comparison operators, like '<' or '>', which might give unexpected results if the string is badly formatted for some reason.  I'm not sure if there is a way to force date to output as an integer or not...

References:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: Do you know why Tom's solution wouldn't be removing the '\r' characters? I can't seem to get around this problem...